# Developing Heroku addon in non-Ruby language

Tags: heroku

I read [this documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/building-an-add-on) but I'm very confused about it. They provide examples for the Ruby language, but is it possible to do this in an other language, like Java and Spring for example? I tried to look up some examples on how to implement this but I can't find any.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can build Heroku add-ons in languages besides Ruby.

From [the page you linked to](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/building-an-add-on):

> Because add-ons are cloud services, you can develop them in whatever
>   language and framework you prefer. Add-ons are *not* required to run on
>   Heroku.
>
> The primary technical requirements for an add-on are:
>
> - It must be able to receive HTTPS requests.
> - It must be able to parse JSON.